# Sending mail to thousands of customers at a time ( wp_mail -Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

I want to send a total of 1650 mails on Christmas eve from a WordPress website.

This is my current code:

```
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=" . get_bloginfo('charset') . "" . "\r\n";

$customers = get_users($args);
$cus_arr = array();
foreach($customers as $customer){
            array_push($cus_arr,$customer->data->user_email);
 }
wp_mail($cus_arr, $subject, $message, $headers);

/*another way*/
...
    foreach($customers as $customer){
       wp_mail($customer->data->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
     }
```

> Question 1 : Is the above way a good choice for sending a mail to this amount of customers? May there be any problem? Is there any better way of doing it?

Also I dont want customers to see each others mail. This is my current code:

```
wp_mail(array("BCC: xyz@xyz.com","BCC: abc@abc.com"), $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But it does not work. Without `BCC:` the mails are actually sent.

> Question 2. How can I prevent users from seeing other mail ids?

Comment: You're not really sending 1650 messages; you're sending 1 message to 1650 recipients. It's generally better to send each message separately as that allows you to deal with unsubscribe requests much better.

Comment: @Synchro : yes I wrote the topic as send  mail to thousands of customers

Comment: @Synchro : you mean to say the another way (pls check my above edit ) will be good  ?

Comment: If you send messages individually, recipients won’t see each other’s addresses, same goes for a single message with BCC.

Comment: @Synchro but sending a mail in a loop of 1650 customers.will there be any problem ? Also I am using sendgrid API puu.sh/yL3eO/705d387655.png .

Comment: Yes, other than that you should not run a potentially slow script like that from a browser, but via cron or other scheduler. 1,650 messages is not many, though check whether sendgrid has a BCC limit, in which case you'll need to divide your list into chunks.

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1:** It's good practice to use a rate limit(throttling), e.g. max 100 mails/10 minutes. You can do this by storing the recipients in a database, and use a cronjob to send mail every 10 minutes. Another option is to use a 3rd party mail service, such as Mandrill or Sendgrid, they'll handle throttling for you.

**Question 2:** Your current code calls wp_mail for each recipient, so they'll never see other mail addresses (no need for BCC headers). However if you decide to use wp_mail to send to multiple recipients in 1 call, you need to use bcc headers, e.g.:

```
wp_mail('', $subject, $message, array("BCC: xyz@xyz.com","BCC: abc@abc.com"));
```

Comment: I am using sendgrid API http://puu.sh/yL3eO/705d387655.png . So can I use my method directly?

Comment: Also , if we put that array in header then where to put this--> `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=" . get_bloginfo('charset') . "" . "\r\n";`

Comment: $headers can be an array without the line breaks, e.g. `array("MIME-Version: 1.0","Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8","BCC: xyz.xyz.com")`

Answer (score 1):

Hey there I think your code is a bad idea because of the following reasons:

- The script may exceed the max execution time or the memory limit of the server
- it ***may*** work, but `wp_mail` is just not a good solution for sending this huge amount of emails

What I would recommend is to use a library for sending bulk e-mails. There are existing WordPress Plugins for this purpose however you can easily do it yourself - here is my solution with the classic, well tested PHPMailerLibrary (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer):

*In your functions.php:*

```
    require("libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

/**
@param $from: The senders E-Mail
@param $from_name: The senders Name
@param $subject: The E-Mail subject
@param $mesesage: The E-Mail content HTML
@param $to: An array of receivers
*/
function my_custom_send_mass_mail($from,$from_name,$subject,$message,$to) {

        // first use PHPMailer to send all the emails
        $email = new PHPMailer();

        $email->isSMTP();  
        $email->CharSet   = 'utf-8';
        $email->From      = $from;
        $email->FromName  = $from_name;
        $email->Subject   = $subject;
        $email->Body      = $message;
        $email->IsHTML();


        if(is_array($to)) {
            foreach($to as $t) {
                $email->addBCC($t);
            }
        }

        $ac = time();
        update_option('mailsent-'.$ac,$email);

        $success = $email->send(); 

        if($success) {
           update_option('mailsent-suc-'.$ac,"yes");
           return "Bulk E-Mail successfully sent.";
        } 
        update_option('mailsent-suc-'.$ac,$email->ErrorInfo);
        return "Bulk E-Mail Error: Please contact admin.";
    }
```

Just call this function and make sure $to is the array of receiver e-mails.

This is the solution I am using for a customer sending a 10000 E-Mail newsletter weekly and it works great so far.

Comment: but its going in spam

Comment: This is most probably not a problem of the Mail script. Check your headers and contents. This guide from mailchimp may help improving your emails: https://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/avoid-spam-filters/

Comment: Also read this: https://optinmonster.com/11-reasons-why-your-emails-go-in-the-spam-box-and-how-to-make-sure-they-dont/

Comment: Doesn't wp_mail() use PHPMailer?

Comment: @RickHellewell This is an old answer, might habe changed. Afaik it just uses PHPs mail() function internally.

Comment: @Blackbam - if you look at the source for wp_mail, you can see that PHPMailer is used to send (around line 255). 
 Although I can't find a filter in wp_mail to override PHPMailer settings.

Comment: @RickHelwell That filter would be a nice MR for Wordpress?